# $|f(t) |=1$ if $f(z) =\sum_{}^{}a_{n} z^n$ for given $a_{n}$.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, power-series

Let $$a_{n}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{(-1)^k}{k!} & if \ n=2(2k+1) , k\in \mathbb{N}\\ 
 \frac{(-1)^k i}{k!}& if \ n=4k \ , k \in \mathbb{N} ,  & \\ 
 0&  Otherwise.& 
\end{matrix}\right.$$
and Let :
$$f(z)=\sum_{}^{}a_{n} z^n$$
Prove that $|f(t)|=1$ for any real t .
we have by inspection:
$$
(1-i)f(z)=i\  cos(z) + cosh(z)$$
So $$|f(t)|=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(cos^2t + cosh^2t)$$

Comment: Since $cosh$ is unbounded while $cos$ is, if your last formula is right, the result you seek is false ;)

Comment: I get $f(z)=(i+z^2)\mathrm{e}^{-z^4}$...

Comment: Right. It should probably have been $(2k+1)!$ resp. $(2k)!$ in the denominators.

Comment: Right, I get $i\mathrm{e}^{-iz^2}$ with $(2k+1)!$ resp., $(2k)!$ in the corresponding denominators. @DanielFischer `;)`.